# Google admin sdk returns only 5000 user in one domain

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to retrieve all users in a domain using the google apps admin sdk. I have 10000+ users in that domain. However every time I send a request it returns only 5000 users. After the first 5000 users are returned, the request resets and I receive the same 5000 users again.

I have also noticed that at the end of first 5000 requests, the next page token is blank.

I need help to retrieve all users in my domain. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share with us your GET request and response?

Comment: @user2676491 did you fix this... i don't get a pageToken returned either !